# Is it possible to create an Geotracking app in WP7 using Bing Maps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, geotagging

Is it possible to create an app like Runtastic, RunKeeper or SportsTracker (all of them Android apps) in WP7 using Bing Maps? Or maybe there is an app with that functionality already out?

These apps basically trace the route you run/cycle/jogg/etc in Google maps, displaying your current speed, altitude, cal lost, direction, etc. Then they have an option for storing the tracks and displaying their related information later. They can display charts as well.

Also, what sensors does WP7 devices have?

The image below is runtastic, tracing the path as you go
[image: runtastic]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. But you should get past the idea stage and into the development before posting questions here.

As for what sensors are available, you can find more information about the minimum hardware specifications [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_7#Minimum_requirements)

A WP7 device must, at a minimum have the following:

- **Accelerometer with Compass**
- **Assisted GPS**
- Ambient light Sensor
- Proximity Sensor
- Camera with LED flash
- FM radio tuner

Comment: The device *accelerometer* is not needed for geotracking because it doesn't measure the acceleration in space (coordinate acceleration) but rather the weight fluctuation. Also, you don't need a compass for this either - it's all done by the GPS sensor that tracks the movement in space. The speed can be measured by comparing coordinates and the position can be easily translated on a map control (in this case, Bing Maps).

Comment: @Dennis Delimarsky you are correct that it is not required for geocoding, however, depending on the design of the app it can be used very effectively in displaying additionally relevant information. As to the rest of my list, it was provided because the OP's question was "what sensors does WP7 devices have?" You have criticized my answer twice now, yet I see no real additional value in your answer outside the multitasking warning. Please reserve your downvotes for incorrect or otherwise invalid answers, not just your "competition".

Answer (score 1):

It is possible since you can translate existing [GPS coordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to the Bing Maps control. Must of the features Chris mentioned are **not required** for a geotracking application (those are general device requirements). All that's needed is basically the GPS sensor.

Note one important element - you will not be able to run the application as a background process. Although you can keep it under the lock screen, you will not be able to switch to other processes (only to a [very limited extent and under specific conditions](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx)).